# Почему возникает ошибка при тесте на девайсе? Could not launch "Hallo World"

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Could not launch "Hallo World". Process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 12053.

кароче на ipod запускаеться моё приложение.Показываеться лаунч картинка, и вылетает с определённом сообщением. Но сама иконка находиться в устройстве, её нажимаешь и нормально пользуешься приложением.

хотя при тесте на симуляторе всё нормально, без ошибок вообще.

Answer (score 1):

а просто удалить приложение с пода и вновь запустить через x-code не пробовали? так же на всякий случай проверьте build phases и build settings для своего проекта, в частности там где настраиваются сертификаты. Скорее всего у Вас спутанные  developer и distribution